# Export to Excel not downloading excel file

Tags: c#, excel

[image]I have this code snippet I have been using for a while on most of my web applications to export data from database to excel, but doesn't seem to work for me anymore.

```
 var recDownload = GetDownload();
            var excel = new ExcelPackage();
            var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("recDownload");
            var totalCols = recDownload.Columns.Count;
            var totalRows = recDownload.Rows.Count;

            for (var col = 1; col <= totalCols; col++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, col].Value = recDownload.Columns[col - 1].ColumnName;
            }
            for (var row = 1; row <= totalRows; row++)
            {
                for (var col = 0; col < totalCols; col++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[row + 1, col + 1].Value = recDownload.Rows[row - 1][col];
                }
            }
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=products.xlsx");
                excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

This is the error I get while debugging

> Length =
>   '((System.Web.HttpResponseStream)Response.OutputStream).Length' threw
>   an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>
> Position =
>   '((System.Web.HttpResponseStream)Response.OutputStream).Position'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>
> ReadTimeout = 'Response.OutputStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception
>   of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>
> WriteTimeout = 'Response.OutputStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception
>   of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Post the actual exception you are getting during runtime, not just the watch window exceptions...

Comment: Thread has been aborted

Comment: At which call? And does it fail at that point every time? Can you provide the Callstack? I have a feeling it's something in the lib you're using...

Comment: You are right, seem to be coming from the package @ 
var excel = new ExcelPackage();

am using EPPlus library

Comment: I got it sorted, I had an "Update Panel" on my page all along. Had to add the button that was calling export to excel method to postback trigger

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I knew the issue was somewhere not in the code share in the question so I couldn't help as I don't have access to your repo ;)

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. Do you resolve it? I have no mistake in code (without any exception) but download process is not started.